# scala : Memory allocation for "def"

Tags: scala, memory, memory-management

If it was said that "functions are first class values" does it mean that 
in case when we use "def" for variable declarations, the memory allocation to store the value will take place ?

Comment: No. `def` declares [methods, not functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529184/difference-between-method-and-function-in-scala).

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Difference between method and function in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529184/difference-between-method-and-function-in-scala).

Comment: Also, there is no such thing as "memory allocation" in Scala.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Could you please elaborate your statement, please... Do you mean because scala use JVM it follow the java memory allocation principle or you mean something more ?

Comment: @TimFlorian: No, I mean because the Scala Language Specification does not say anything about memory allocation and leaves it up to the individual implementation how to allocate memory. Also, it is not true that Scala uses the JVM. The Scala Language Specification does not require usage of the JVM. And for example, Scala.js does not use the JVM, and Scala-native also does not use the JVM.